# Making a Vim theme that disables highlighting except for some special keywords

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Inspired by several posts, like [Your syntax highlighter is wrong](https://medium.com/@MrJamesFisher/your-syntax-highlighter-is-wrong-6f83add748c9), [Coding in color](https://medium.com/@evnbr/coding-in-color-3a6db2743a1e) and [A case against syntax highlighting](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/syntaxhighlighting/) and some others, I decided making a Vim theme that applied some of these concepts would be a good idea.

The thing is I'm not exactly sure how.

From what I can tell, in order to make a Vim theme you need to basically link a color with a syntax identifier or name. And repeat this hundreds or dozens of time in order to have in your lap a theme.

Like for example linking the color `#ff0000` (red) and the syntax identifier, or key, `Error`. As an example. Not sure if that's actually the syntax key.

This would work fine, except that, every syntax that I don't consider important I have to define as just a default foreground value.

And let's say I wanted to add a new syntax keyword, I'd have to do it with `ftsyntax` and stuff (I believe) and that would be filetype specific etc.

So the first question is:

What would be the best way to give *everything* a default foreground color and only pick the exceptions to have some colors?

And the second, perhaps more important question is:

How do I syntax highlight a specific piece of text without having to add a syntax rule? For example have a regex that finds any `=` and highlights them green, without having to add a syntax rule specific for that.

Any help is appreciated. Of course if the approach I'm taking to this is not ideal or sucks I am open to suggestions to alternatives. Thank you. :)

Comment: After answering I think I may have completely misread your question. Do you want to make a vim color-scheme, or a syntax highlight file..?

Comment: @Caek The idea is to make Vim work more like what those posts I linked describe. Whatever means I don't particularly mind if it works. Unless of course it would mean altering the Vim source code. ;)

Comment: I've undeleted my answer as it explains how to create a basic syntax file to highlight the things you requested. But if you want to edit the way that comments and other things look, you'll have to edit your vim color scheme.

Comment: The more times I read your question the more I think I've answered it wrong. Unfortunately I don't know anything about editing the color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

See the example syntax file below:

```
syn keyword myKeywords   We Are Important Keywords
syn match myEquals       '='

hi link myKeywords       Special
hi link myEquals         Operator
```

This will put **We**, **Are**, **Important** and **Keywords** into the myKeywords syntax group and **=** into the myEquals syntax group.
Then we specify how we want to highlight them, by linking it to the **Special** and **Operator** highlight groups.

See: `:help group-name` for a list of the highlight groups and what the colors look like with your color-scheme.

In my color-scheme, **Special** is Red and **Operator** is green.
By default, everything else is set to the default foreground color.

I saved this to `~/.vim/syntax/greduan.vim` and tested with `:set syntax=greduan`

Answer (score 0):

Your question touches two domains:

- syntax definition
- syntax highlighting

Syntax definition, as in Caek's answer, is simple for the first 10 minutes but grows very quickly into a major PITA because it is a core aspect of Vim's architecture with ramifications far beyond syntax highlighting.

Syntax highlighting has its pitfalls but it is a lot simpler than syntax definition.

I think that you can tackle the problem described in those blog posts with syntax highlighting first and, if needed, graduate to syntax definition.

1. Grab a simple colorscheme like [Busybee](https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes/blob/master/colors/busybee.vim).
2. Link all the highlight groups you don't need to `Normal` while leaving the ones you want to keep:

   ```
   hi link Foo Normal
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the best way to give everything a default foreground
>   color and only pick the exceptions to have some colors?

What is best depends ... for me the best, because quickest way was clearing unwanted highlighting in ~/.vimrc:

```
sy on
hi c Constant|hi c Error|hi c PreProc|hi c Special|hi c Statement|hi c Type
hi c Identifier
```

> How do I syntax highlight a specific piece of text without having to
>   add a syntax rule?

If by *syntax rule* you mean *syntax item*, I'd say you cannot have syntax highlighting without defining syntax items.